WeberE definition from Wikipedia doesn't match the definition from Wolfram Language?
According to Wikipedia - Struve function: Relation to other functions the WeberE function should return this, if the first argument is a negative integer:
$$
\mathbf{E}_{-n}(z) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \right \rfloor} \frac{\Gamma(n-k-\frac{1}{2}) \left (\frac{z}{2} \right )^{-n+2k+1}}{\Gamma \left (k+ \frac{3}{2} \right)}-\mathbf{H}_{-n}(z)
$$
But in Wolfram language it only returns a formula with an alternating sign from the corresponding positive integer argument?
>> Table[WeberE[n, z], {n, 1, 10}] == Table[(-1)^n*WeberE[n, z], {n, -1, -10,-1}]

True

Is the WeberE function for negative first integer argument defined different from the Wikipedia definition?
Update: the Wikipedia equation is edited now. See below

I not a expert in this case but Relations Between Anger's and Weber's Function is:WeberE[-n, x] == Cos[n  Pi] WeberE[n, x] - Sin[n  Pi] AngerJ[n, x] .Maybe this series is wrong and Mathematica gives correct answer.

Relations Between Anger's and Weber's Function  you can find in the book: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf   12.3.4 on page: 498

The question is about the relation to the StruveH function. The definitions from 12.3.6 and 12.3.7 seem to be the same as in Wikipedia.

So I was right,in my comment.

There is a mistake on Wikipedia the upper bound in the sum should be Ceiling[(n - 3)/2]}] instead of Floor[(n - 1)/2]. Please correct the Wikipedia page.
z = Sqrt[3];
N[Table[WeberE[-n, z] == (-1)^(n + 1)/π Sum[(Gamma[1 n - k - 1/2] (z/2)^(-n + 2 k + 1))/
      Gamma[k + 3/2], {k, 0, Ceiling[(n - 3)/2]}] - 
    StruveH[-n, z], {n, 1, 10}], 10]


{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}


You referring to this formula 11.10.23?
https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10#vi

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Struve_function

I am referring to the formula in your OP that was taken from Wikipedia link also in your OP. I edited the wiki page myself.
